# Do not commit offset when exception is thrown in camel-kafka

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using camel-kafka component. We have to follow strict ordering and we can not afford message loss. Thus in the case of some exception, we do not want to commit the offset. I have set **autoCommitEnable=false** and not handling the exception. BUT no matter which exception is thrown offset is getting committed (Only the stacktrace gets printed.)

To handler this scenario , I changed the source code in camel-kafka. Here is the snippet:

```
 try {
        KafkaConsumer.this.processor.process(exchange);
        if (KafkaConsumer.this.endpoint.getConfiguration().isAutoCommitEnable() != null
                && !KafkaConsumer.this.endpoint.getConfiguration().isAutoCommitEnable()
                        .booleanValue()) {
            this.consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition,
                    new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() + 1L)));
// Commit one by one
        }
    } catch (Exception arg13) {
        KafkaConsumer.this.getExceptionHandler().handleException("Error during processing",
                exchange, arg13);
        if (KafkaConsumer.LOG.isTraceEnabled()) {
            KafkaConsumer.LOG.trace(
                    "Caught an exception while processing partition {}, Kafka message (offset = {}) ",
                    Integer.valueOf(record.partition()), Long.valueOf(record.offset()));
        }
        break; // Break in case of any exception 
    }
```

BUT here also no luck. Even if I write handler or not, flow does not come in Catch block. Thus offset is always getting commiitted. is it the normal behavior ? How can I stop camel to commit offset in case of exception ?

I can see there is property in spring-kakfa **"ackOnError"**. Do we have similar property in camel-kafka (I was not able to find any)? Please help.

Comment: Have you set the `autoCommitEnable`? or `Enabled`? read carefully http://camel.apache.org/kafka.html

Comment: Bear in mind that even spring-kafka's `ackOnError` has limited functionality, since the next successful message will commit its offset. You have to stop the consumer (and fix the problem) when such a condition occurs.

Comment: @SergeyBenner Yes. As I mentioned in the question, I have set autoCommitEnable=false. Corrected the typo.

Comment: @GaryRussell Yes. I know that.

Answer (score 0):

And Finally, After much debugging I can see that camel does not propagate the exception back and it sets it in exchange as a property "Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT". So here is the sample code which I wrote by changing in the KafkaConsumer.java#run class of camel-kafka to not commit the offset in case of an exception.

```
try {
      KafkaConsumer.this.processor.process(exchange);
      Throwable e1 = (Throwable) exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT , Throwable.class);
        if (e1 != null) {
                throw e1;
            }
            if (KafkaConsumer.this.endpoint.getConfiguration().isAutoCommitEnable() != null
                                        && !KafkaConsumer.this.endpoint.getConfiguration().isAutoCommitEnable()
                                                .booleanValue()) {
            this.consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition,
                                            new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() + 1L)));
            }
            } 
            catch (Throwable arg13) {
                KafkaConsumer.this.getExceptionHandler().handleException("Error during processing",
                                        exchange, arg13);
                    break;
            }
```

So far this example working for me and working fine. If anyone is Camel or Kafka expert, let me know if there could be any consequences of doing this because I have not found any.